# Replace whitespaces between specific characters in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regexp (or any other solution) that would let me replace all whitespace characters between specific non whitespace chars. Eg:

```
instance. method
instance .method
"instance" .method
instance. "method"
```

Is it possible?

EDIT:

In other words - I want to throw out whitespace if it's between letter and dot, dot and letter, quotation mark and dot or dot and quotation mark.

Comment: i do not think you can do this with regexp alone

Comment: Ofcourse this is possible -- as long as i am allowed to specify what those "specific non whitespace" chars and other constraints are. Please make your question more specific about those "specific" non-ws chars.

Comment: Any solution would be much appreciated. Currently I'm stuck so feel free to suggest anything :)

Comment: will there always be an `instance` var name?

Comment: @elgonzo - I edited my question, @T McKeown - no, it was just an example

Comment: what rules can you hang your hat on?  so far you want a space parser... that's very generic

Comment: “Any solution”? Here's one: `return string.Empty;`. That does exactly what you asked for. It's not what you want? Then you must tell us what you want.

Comment: For example, use `Regex.Replace("[abc]\s+[abc]", "replacementString") - replaces all white-space sequences between any combinations of the characters a, b or cwith "replacementString" (including the matched a, b, c characters). That works... for me... i made up my own rules/conditions/constraints... hope you like it as well ;)

Comment: @elgonzo please post your comment as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: What about any other characters, like comma, colon, slashes, single quotes, hyphens, parantheses, etc...? For them the rule should not apply?

Comment: @elgonzo - no, only the characters I mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\s+(?=\\.)|(?<=\\.)\\s+(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=\")\\s+(?=\\.)|(?<=\\.)\\s+(?=\")");

Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("instance. method", ""));
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("instance .method", ""));
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("\"instance\" .method", ""));
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("instance. \"method\"", ""));
```

Result:

```
instance.method
instance.method
"instance".method
instance."method"
```

The regex has four parts:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=\.) //Matches [a-zA-Z] before and . after:

(?<=\.)\s+(?=[a-zA-Z]) //Matches . before and [a-zA-Z] after

(?<=")\s+(?=\.) //Matches " before and . after

(?<=\.)\s+(?=") //Matches . before and " after
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Well, that's a regexp I wouldn't be able to write on my own :). Thanks!

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov How did you create this beautiful image?

Comment: Nice image there showing the regex. Totally unrelated to the original question, but: How did you make it? Damn, Juan beat me to it :-D

Answer (score 4):

> I want to throw out whitespace if it's between letter and dot, dot and letter, quotation mark and dot or dot and quotation mark.

I would use something like this:

```
@"(?i)(?:(?<=\.) (?=[""a-z])|(?<=[""a-z]) (?=\.))"
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fW5dW2)

Or broken down:

```
(?i)           // makes the regex case insensitive.
(?:
  (?<=\.)      // ensure there's a dot before the match
  [ ]          // space (enclose in [] if you use the expanded mode, otherwise, you don't need []
  (?=[a-z""])  // ensure there's a letter or quote after the match
|              // OR
  (?<=[a-z""]) // ensure there's a letter or quote before the match
  [ ]          // space
  (?=\.)       // ensure there's a dot after the match
)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

In a variable:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(?i)(?:(?<=\.) (?=[""a-z])|(?<=[""a-z]) (?=\.))");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for/to search on google is "Character LookAhead and LookBehind"... basically what you want to do is use RegEx to find all instances of whitespace characters or split the string by Whitespace (i prefer this one), and then look ahead and behind on each match and see if the char at those positions (previous and next) match your criteria. Then replace if necessary at that position.

Unfortunately i do not know of a "single statement" solution for what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string with word bounds:

```
^([\w\".]*)([\s])([\w\".]*)$
```

$1 will give you the first part.
$2 will give you the white space.
$3 will give you the end part.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you seek?  ([regex101 link](http://regex101.com/r/hD2iF1))

```
[A-Za-z"](\s)\.|\.(\s)[A-Za-z"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(instance, "([\\w\\d\".])\\s([\\w\\d\".])", "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternate and simple solution would be to split the string on dot and then trim them.